# Use async/await on all actions in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

Is it ok to make **all actions async**, all the way to the managers and functions that read from the db (using LINQ's asyncs)?

**Does it bring any benefits?**

e.g. in controller:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> EditNewsAsync(int id)
{
    var newsReader = new NewsReader();
    var news = await newsReader.GetAsync(id);
    return this.PartialView("_AddEditNews", news);
}
```

in NewsReader.cs:

```
public async override Task<News> GetAsync(int id)
{
    using (var ctx = new KreditorWebEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<News> query = from n in ctx.News
                    where n.new_id == id
                    select new News { Id = n.new_id, 
                                      UserId = n.new_fk_addedByUserId,
                                      AddedDatetime = n.new_addedDatetime,
                                      ShowOnlyOnce = n.new_showOnlyOnce,
                                      Text = n.new_text };

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 5):

> Does it bring any benefits?

It brings benefit if you need ***scalability***. The point of using async IO instead of synchronous blocking API's is that you release the thread once your query is on-going. If you don't need that, and you have limited requests querying your endpoint that the ASP.NET threadpool can handle, then you'll see no benefit in going `async`.

Don't go full out "async all the things" just because you can. Use it wisely and understand the overhead that `async` brings to your code.

Comment: It does provide scalability - but only as long as the db can handle the scaled load.

Comment: @StephenCleary You're right, I assume that's a given thing. When one bottleneck is resolved, the next one rises.